# How publish flutter/flame game to github pages?

Tags: flutter, github-pages

I'm trying to use GitHub pages to publish my flutter/flame game. Ideally I want to have the source directory to be build/web/ on my main branch but you can only choose from /(root) or docs/. For this reason I chose to deploy from a branch I made called ghpages and then just copy the contents of build/web/ into that branch as you can see in the second picture. But I get a blank page and various errors in the console, see third picture. I'm having trouble figuring out why.

Link to ghpages deployment: https://squinnb.github.io/game/

[image: github pages settings]

[image: github pages repo]

[image: chrome console for deployment]